# Exponential function is always positive

Tags: real-analysis

Now since $\mathrm{exp}(0) = 1 > 0$ and because $\mathrm{exp}$ is continuous, it cannot change sign because it would have to go through a zero (by IVT). Hence $\mathrm{exp}(x)>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

My question: I don't understand how we know that $\mathrm{exp}(x)$ does not go through a zero, and thereby change sign. Would someone care to elaborate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is defined so it is always positive.

Comment: Well I'm trying to understand the argumentation presented above.

Comment: Which properties of $\exp$ may be used? If we may Invest that $\exp(x)\not=0$ for all $x$ it IS easy, as described. Otherwise you should apply something like $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ for $y=-x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose there exists $x$ such that $e^x = 0$. But consider: by a known property and since the exponential is defined for all real $x$, we notice $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = e^0 = 1$.

But this directly contradicts $e^x = 0$ (otherwise the product would be zero), so there is no such zero.